In c#, why does a string composed of (byte)'\n' not contain '\n'?
I just discovered that the code below returns false:
((byte)'\n').ToString().Contains('\n') // -> false

While this one returns true:
'\n'.ToString().Contains('\n') // -> true

Why is that? The char codes of (byte)'\n' and (char)'\n' are the same since '\n' == 10.
This number can be expressed as both a byte (1B) and a char (2B) because 10 < 256, so the stored value should be the same no matter the encoding...
I don't have a clue why this happens, being relatively new to typed languages.

Did you look at what the documentation for Byte.ToString() says? Did you inspect the return value of ((byte) '\n').ToString()? (It's not what you're expecting...)

'\n'.ToString() converts the char \n to string, and the result is a one character string with a newline.
(see the documentation for Char.ToString).
► When you check if it contains a newline, the result is naturally true.
((byte)'\n').ToString() first converts the char \n to a byte, meaning a 8 bit intergral value of value 10. Then 10 is converted to string and the result is "10".
(see the documentation for Byte.ToString).
► This string does not contain a newline and therefore you get false from Contains.
You can observe it using the following snippet:
var s1 = '\n'.ToString();
var s2 = ((byte)'\n').ToString();

If you use you debugger you'll see that s1 is "\n" (i.e. a string with one newline character) but s2 is "10".
